# Creating a data frame of missing values

Tags: r, merge

I am working with petroleum company financial data and exploration data in RStudio

I have two data frames, *AS* and *xpl*.

When merging the two with
`merged = xpl %>% inner_join(AS, by=c("NPD_id", "year"))`, I lose some 90 observations from *xpl*.

Is there an easy way to create a new data frame from these missing 90 observations?
A command which tells R to look for observations found in *xpl*, but not *merged*, and disregard the observations which are present in both frames maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `anti_join`. Without data, it is difficult to tell though.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data (in general), it may be better to do `left_join(xpl, AS, ...)` instead of inner-join, then split the data based on `NA` values in one of the `AS`-columns. To use `inner_join` and `anti_join` goes through two join operations, whereas `left_join` and some form of split is only one join-op. YMMV.

Comment: `anti_join` did the trick, thanks.